# How to parse JSON with shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a JSON file from which I need to extract a few parameters and write into another file:

```
devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.9.1",
"gulp-bump": "^1.0.0"
}
```

I want to write a file that contains only

```
gulp gulp-angular-templatecache gulp-bump
```

How can I do that using a shell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with UNIX tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet... ;-)

Comment: As I am new in jq, I have use it in conjunction with shell. I am pretty sure this can be handle by jq alone. I just strip out portion of data from the jason file using jq and then use shell to remove quotes from the string using shell.:
jq ".devDependencies | to_entries[] | .key" package.json > devdep

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(grep ^\" file| cut -d\" -f2)
```

But you shouldn't do any more complex json parsing with bash. This is also a hackish solution.

Comment: Any better idea how I can do this?

Comment: Thanks. I have used below command and able to extract the portion like below:
cat package.json | `pwd`/jq  '.devDependencies'

{
  "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
  "chai": "^3.4.1",
  "del": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.9.1",
  "gulp-bump": "^1.0.0"
}
Now I really wanted to extract the keys of every field (e.g. angular-cookies chai del ...)
Not able to figure how I can do that? appreciate your help