# How to request curl http and parse the JSON response in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl, apigee

```
URL=$(curl -i -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic token=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "http://company url:8080/v1/organizations/wiley/environments/api-team-ci1/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=01/24/2017%2002:00~01/25/2017%2006:00")
```

URL should return a JSON response which I need to parse and grab some values. Not even getting response from the curl command; getting only "curl: no URL specified!" error. Please help me and direct as I am trying to do it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the URL as an argument to `-H`, but it's not a header – remove the `-H` before the URL:

```
url=$(curl -i -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic token=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
"http://company url:8080/v1/organizations/wiley/environments/api-team-ci1/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=01/24/2017%2002:00~01/25/2017%2006:00")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After I posted the question I was trying different ways and was able to get response successfully. It's JSON response. Could you tell me how do I find a particular error value (which is 6 here) and if it goes above 10 an email will be generated. please see the response below -
 {
  "environments" : [ {
    "dimensions" : [ {
      "metrics" : [ {
        "name" : "sum(is_error)",
        "values" : [ "6.0" ]
      } ],
      "name" : "asiag-api"
    } ],
    "name" : "api-xyz"
  } ],
  "metaData" : {
    "errors" : [ ],

Comment: You're asking "how to parse JSON" and "how to send email from the command line", which seem unrelated to the question at hand. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093119/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting) and [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) for JSON parsing; check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line) for sending mail from the command line.